# Roman numeral and integer calculator c++

Tags: c++

I need to create a roman numbers and integers mix calculator.
I have a class name roman, I upload the operators but I am having a problem converting and having a constructor. I think I need two constructors for string and int.
I have that so far. int main() must stay same. I am looking for help.

```
class roman
{
    string roman_input; //for string input
    int num_input; //for integer input

public:

    roman()
    {
        roman_input = "";
        num_input = 0;
    }

    roman(int a, string b)
    {
        roman_input = b;
        num_input = a;
    }


    roman(string s)
    {
        num_input = stoi(s);
    }

    roman(char* a)
    {
        roman temp = roman(std::string(a));
        this->num_input = temp.num_input;
        this->roman_input = temp.roman_input;
    }

    roman operator+ (const roman& c) const //+ operator overload
    {
        roman result;
        result.roman_input = (this->roman_input + c.roman_input);
        result.num_input = (this->num_input + c.num_input);

        return result;

    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const roman& r) //  << operator overload
    {
        os << r.num_input  << r.roman_input;
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    roman r1 = 1234;
    roman r2 = "DLXVII"; // 567
    roman r3 = r1 + r2;

    cout << r1 << " + " << r2 << " = " << r3;
    cin.get();
}

//Produces the following output :
//MCCXXXIV + DLXVII = MDCCCI
```

Comment: I don't think `stoi` will convert a Roman numeral. You will need to write your own converter.

Comment: Why not just transform the roman representation to/from normal numbers and do everything internally with integer datatypes ? This would save you a lot of work implementing basic number operations.